# How to solve the "Undefined variable" error in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel, and I got an error:

> Undefined variable: getFormTest (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\survey\resources\views\tambahformtest.blade.php)

That error references to this view:

```
<input value="{{ $getFormTest[0]->ms_test }}">
```

I have put `$getFormTest` in my controller:

```
public function TambahFormTest()
{
    $ms_id = FormTest::max('ms_id');
    $getFormTest = FormTest::Select('ms_test')->where('ms_id', '=', $ms_id)->get();

    return view('tambahformtest', $getFormTest);
}
```

Comment: The Select probably returns nothing which makes the 0 index invalid/undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: `return("view.blade")->with(["getFormTest" => $getFormTest]);`: This will allow you to access `{{ $getFormTest }}` in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When returning a view in laravel, you have to pass an array of params.

```
return view ('myView', ['param1' => $v1, 'param2', $v2]);
```

then in your view

```
@if(isset($param1) 
   {{ $params->property }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a use of `compact` method of php

```
public function TambahFormTest()
{
    $ms_id = FormTest::max('ms_id');
    $getFormTest = FormTest::Select('ms_test')->where('ms_id', '=', $ms_id)->get();

    return view('tambahformtest', compact('getFormTest'));
}
```

This would be sent to view as - `['getFormTest' => $getFormTest]`

Hope this helps